# List showing the last 3 items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, slider

I use this code for my slider in my view
but I want to show the last 3 items

```
    <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.blog)
                {
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="@item.postImage" width="100%" alt="PostImage" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" />
                            <p class="flex-caption">@item.postTitle</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: so change your code to count how many items are in the collection and only display the last 3. What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                @foreach (var item in ((List<your Model>)ViewBag.blog).Skip(((List<your Model>)ViewBag.list).Count-3))
                {
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="@item.postImage" width="100%" alt="PostImage" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" />
                            <p class="flex-caption">@item.postTitle</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
```